OSGeo4W unable to get setup.ini
Actually with the QGIS installation of owgeo4w we tried to fix an other error. The standalone installation of Version 3.34.11 was successful, only the plugins did not work due to the error that the plugin repositories are not connected. To solve this error the idea was to install QGIS with osgeo4w. Only to get the next error:


Are you on a corporate network behind a proxy?  Settings - Options - Network - Use Proxy for Web Access.

Yes, in an university network. But we tried it with vpn connection. Also the it service couldn't help. And the same error occured also at home with private internet connection.

It was an checkmark on the wrong position. With win 10, simply unchecked the box for local network/proxy server settings for Lan and everything was working.

